# How to check if a scrollbar is visible with only CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to check if a scrollbar is present with only CSS?

I want to add padding to an element if it has a scrollbar, and no padding if it doesn't. I don't want to use JavaScript.

Comment: I guess it's impossible wih CSS alone

Comment: No you cannot check it using only CSS, you have to use jQuery/JS

Comment: This requires use of conditional statement which CSS alone cannot do.

Comment: It's 2022 now, does that changed?

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, there is a pure CSS way of calculating the size of the scrollbar:

`:root {  --scrollbar-width: calc(100vw - 100%) }`

the variable will be 0 when there is no scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

A rather manual way to go about this without javascript is to test your responsiveness and note the screen-width at which the scrollbar gets added. Then set your media query at that which to apply the padding.